# Downloading WFS data using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, wfs, qgis-3

I tried to download data from WFS server but it doesn´t work with Qgis 3.2.2.
I connected to https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_alkis_vereinfacht Then I connect to server and wanted to preselect a specific area by

1. Query e.g. select * from flurstueck where city= 'köln', 
   or:
2. by tagging the "only request features overlapping with the view extent".

But both doesn´t work for me.

---

Failure message:

> Layer ave:Flurstueck : Download of features for layer ave:Flurstueck
>   failed or partially failed: Download of features failed: Error
>   transferring
>   https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_alkis_vereinfacht?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=2.0.0&TYPENAMES=ave:Flurstueck&COUNT=500000&SRSNAME=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::25832&FILTER=%3Cfes:Filter
>   xmlns:fes%3D%22http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0%22%3E%0A
>   %3Cfes:PropertyIsEqualTo%3E%0A
>   %3Cfes:ValueReference%3Egemeinde%3C/fes:ValueReference%3E%0A
>   %3Cfes:Literal%3EKöln%3C/fes:Literal%3E%0A
>   %3C/fes:PropertyIsEqualTo%3E%0A%3C/fes:Filter%3E%0A - server replied:
>   Bad request. You may attempt reloading the layer with F5

Comment: This webservice contains huge amounts of polygons and it seems like this server can't handle huge requests. Have you tried zooming in close enough so you'll only see a couple of streets and then adding the layer with "only request features overlapping with the view extent"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ALKIS-data, especially parcels are usually restricted to be displayed for scale larger than 1:5000, maybe 1:10000, due to the workload they put on the server and the amount of data which needs to be downloaded/transfered.

Try to grab smaller areas, maybe single "Fluren" will work.